# ¿Como agregar el loader skeleton al datatable en reactjs con primereact mientras termina de leer los datos de una api?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, datatables, react-hooks

Soy nuevo usando react y primereact...
la verdad es que entiendo más o menos el uso de datatable y la propiedad de loading y el loader como tal...

Este código es de un archivo .js que sirve como archivo común para todos los datatable existentes en mi proyecto...

Entiendo como activar  el loader pero no consigo que solo me dure el tiempo de carga de datos que consume de la api y tampoco consigo que cargue el skeleton ...
aquí les dejo el código y por cierto, todas las librerías instaladas y funcionando...

Si me ayudan con el ejemplo del código corregido modificado sería lo mejor :3

```
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { Column } from "primereact/column";
import { DataTable } from "primereact/datatable";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { Skeleton } from "primereact/skeleton";

export const DataTableComponet = props => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const { dt, data, selectedItem, setSelectedItem, rows, rowsPerPageOptions, globalFilter, header, columns, getDataFunction, rowExpansionTemplate, expandedRows, onRowToggle, isExpanded } = props;
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
    const [first, setFirst] = useState(0);
    const [last, setLast] = useState(rows);
    const [totalRecords, setTotalRecords] = useState(0);
    const rowCharge = new Array(2);
    const bodyCharge = () => {
        return <Skeleton></Skeleton>;
    };
    useEffect(() => {
        data?.results && setTotalRecords(data.count);
    }, [data]);
    const onPage = async event => {
        setLoading(true);
        const { page, rows, first: _first } = event;
        setFirst(_first);
        setLast(rows);
        await dispatch(getDataFunction(page + 1, rows));
        setLoading(false);
    };
    return (
        <DataTable
            ref={dt}
            value={data?.results || []}
            selection={selectedItem}
            onSelectionChange={e => setSelectedItem(e.value)}
            dataKey="id"
            paginator
            rows={last || 10}
            rowsPerPageOptions={rowsPerPageOptions || [5, 10, 25]}
            className="datatable-responsive"
            globalFilter={globalFilter}
            emptyMessage="No se encontraron datos"
            first={first}
            totalRecords={totalRecords}
            lazy
            onPage={onPage}
            loading={loading}
            paginatorTemplate="FirstPageLink PrevPageLink PageLinks NextPageLink LastPageLink CurrentPageReport RowsPerPageDropdown"
            currentPageReportTemplate="Mostrando del {first} al {last} de {totalRecords} datos"
            header={header}
            rowExpansionTemplate={rowExpansionTemplate}
            expandedRows={expandedRows}
            onRowToggle={onRowToggle}
        >
            {isExpanded && <Column expander style={{ width: "3em" }} />}
            {columns &&
                columns.map((column, index) => {
                    if (column.header) {
                        return <Column key={index} field={column.code} header={column.header} sortable body={column.template}></Column>;
                    } else {
                        return <Column key={index} body={column.template}></Column>;
                    }
                })}
        </DataTable>
    );
};

DataTableComponet.propTypes = {
    dt: PropTypes.any,
    data: PropTypes.any,
    selectedItem: PropTypes.any,
    setSelectedItem: PropTypes.any,
    rows: PropTypes.number,
    rowsPerPageOptions: PropTypes.array,
    globalFilter: PropTypes.any,
    header: PropTypes.any,
    columns: PropTypes.array,
    getDataFunction: PropTypes.any,
    rowExpansionTemplate: PropTypes.any,
    expandedRows: PropTypes.any,
    onRowToggle: PropTypes.any,
    isExpanded: PropTypes.bool
};
```

si me ayudan les estaré eternamente agradecido

Comment: primero que nada, lo que haría es inicializar el hook loading en true para que cuando la aplicación se renderice lo primero que se muestre es que algo se esta cargando, entonces deberias agregar un condicional, donde si el hook `loading` es verdadero, muestro el esqueleto, de lo contrario se renderizan los datos que quieres visualizar

Comment: dentro de un `useEffect` deberias agregar la petición a la api y cuando la petición se complete cambias el hook `loading` a false, para que el condicional que habías agregado haga su trabajo y pueda mostrar loas datos